# Update Multi-Picklist on updating custom object

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have custom object `KeywordAccountAssociation__c`. This object has three fields

1. `Account__c` - Master-Detail(Account)
2. `Keyword__c` - Master-Detail(Keyword)
3. `Compositecp__c` - Text(255) (External ID) (Unique Case Sensitive)

I have a custom field in Account

- `DD_Segment__c` - multi-picklist

Now I want to update (Insert is fine too) values of `DD_Segment__c` whenever `KeywordAccountAssociation__c` is updated. I could write trigger for this but I don't know how? I am new to Salesforce Development and my background is ruby (so getting accustomed to apex is bit difficult for me).

`KeywordAccountAssociation__c` has multiple rows of `Account__c` which has same account_id and those account_id are related to a record of custom object `Keyword__c`. I want to get all keywords related to one account and update in its (account's) multi-picklist. How can I achieve this? If you have doubts about this please do ask. Thanks!

Comment: When you say you want to update/insert values of `DD_Segment__c`, do you mean you want to update the record's value in that field, or actually modify the picklist options that are available to select on the page layout?

Answer (score 1):

One issue is related to learning to work with triggers in general, which can be started with [Salesforce Apex Developer Documents on Triggers](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#CSHID=apex_triggers.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/apex_triggers.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

but to answer your actual question, you would essentially need to build a trigger against your custom object that would update the related account.  It might look something like this:

```
trigger keywordAccountUpdate on KeywordAccountAssociation__c (after insert, after update){
    set<id> = new set<id>();
    for (KeywordAccountAssociation__c a : Trigger.new)
        accountIds.put(a.Account__c);
    map<id,Account> accountMap = new map<id,Account>([select id, DD_Segment__c from Account where id in :accountIds]);
    for (KeywordAccountAssociation__c kaa : Trigger.new){
        if (AccountMap.containskey(kaa.Account__c)){
            Account thisAccount = AccountMap.get(kaa.Account__c);
            String s = thisAccount.DD_Segment__c + ';new value'; // Always add value
            if ((thisAccount.DD_Segment__c).contains('second value')
                s += ';second value';
            AccountsToUpdate.add(new Account(id=thisAccount.id, DD_Segment__c = s));
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that I don't have the structure to test this trigger, I just free handded it, so YMMV.

Comment: where do I get this values from? `new value`, `second value`. I have stored `Keyword_Ids` in `KeywordAccountAssociation`.